# HTML Two pictures side by side positioned, filling out the full width of the explorer window

Tags: html, image, format, height, width

I am looking for a solution to get two pictures side by side positioned, filling out the full width of the explorer window.
The two photos have different formats (portrait and landscape). The two photos in the same row should then both have the same height. For example as in the example photo, but it must not be distorted as shown here.
Is there a way to get it like this?
[image]

Comment: do you display the images with an <img> tag or a background?

Comment: It is better to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

the pictures are displayed like this:

```
<a><img src="leftpicture.jpg" alt="">
</a>
<a><img src="rightpicture.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The HTML: 
   `<div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="image.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="image.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>`

The css:
`<style>
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

`

Comment: Hello MathieuMic, thank you for your answer. I tested your code, but it doesn't work like I want. Now, it looks like the foto in the answer below.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Now they have the same width, but not the same height. Why???
This is the code I use:

html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <a href="Ananasfrucht (1g).JPG" data-lightbox="1-Ananas" data-title="nach ca. 3 Jahren ist der Fruchtansatz erkennbar (nach 1 Woche)">
                <img src="Ananasfrucht (1g).JPG" alt="Ananasfrucht" style="width: 100%">                    
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <a href="Ananasfrucht (2g).JPG" data-lightbox="1-Ananas" data-title="nach ca. 3 Jahren ist der Fruchtansatz erkennbar (nach 1 Woche)">
                <img src="Ananasfrucht (2g).JPG" alt="Ananasfrucht" style="width: 100%">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You might need to set heights for them.

Comment: This is an answer or a question?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of to do this.

The first is to create a `<div>`, and place two `<img>` tags in it, then customize the sizing of the images accordingly. [See this CodePen.](https://codepen.io/akcumeh/pen/ZEvaZaa) (I picked up random photos I found on Google.)

The second way would be to create two divs [under the parent container] and set the desired images as background images for them. [See this other CodePen.](https://codepen.io/akcumeh/pen/rNpYgaQ)

I would personally prefer to use image tags so that I can resize the image quickly and as needed. It's a little more stressful to have to adjust the size and avoid repeating of the background image of the div in my opinion, but of course it all depends on what you are trying to achieve on your site.